# How to make a connection alive between backend and frontend?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I have an application which has frontend written in JavaScript ( backbone) and backend written in Python.

I am currently having a issue, the connection between frontend and backend is terminated after 2 minutes after i initialize a request. The task in backend completes after 4-5 minutes. The Frontend has to wait until it receives a notification from the backend server.

Here is my Scenario,
I send a ajax request to the backend. This is a very costly request that consumes RAM and CPU. This request takes almost more than 3 minutes to complete. After it is completed, the request simply sends back a JSON data with notification saying "Task completed" or "Task Failed" which needs to be displayed to the user.

The Ajax request is very simple request,

```
$.ajax({
    url: server_base_url+"/json_rpc",
    method: "POST",
    headers:headers,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        id: (new Date()).getTime(),
        method: "execute",
        params: params,
    }),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.error) {
            console.log("RPC ERROR",model,method,data.error.message);
        } else {
            console.log("RPC OK",model,method,data.result);
        }
        if (cb) {
            cb(data.error,data.result);
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("RPC ERROR",model,method);
    }
});
```

In the server side, i am using nginx to handle reverse proxy. I have already increased the timeout to 10 minutes (just for test).

The issue i am facing is , when the costly request is made one time, the user will not receive notification even after 5 minutes, as the connection is already terminated after 2-3 minutes (by browser ?). Then the frustated user will refresh the page and hit the same button again sending a new request while the other request might be still processing or completed.

Is there any solution to get out of this issue? Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

Comment: A shot into the dark: Have you also checked the server configuration, for connection timeout?

Comment: Yes i have configured nginx to keep alive connection for more than 10 minutes. But its seems to be the issue with the browser, it somehow terminates the request , adding timeout to the ajax does not seem to work, it is same for safari and chrome which i have tested with similar timings for connection termination.

Comment: I can say the nginx is configured currently because , when i do a remote RPC request, the connection is only terminated after 10 minutes for each request.